# Select rows with time range containing the current time

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-range

I have a Postgres table with the following schema:

```
id | name   | sdate (timestamp)   | edate (timestamp)
---+--------+---------------------+---------------------
1  | test6  | 2013-05-13 01:16:16 | 2013-07-03 10:16:11
2  | test44 | 2012-05-10 10:16:11 | 2013-05-03 00:12:11
3  | test32 | 2013-02-03 00:16:12 | 2013-05-03 00:56:15
4  | test2  | 2013-01-05 08:16:11 | 2014-04-03 10:26:11
6  | test3  | 2013-01-03 00:16:12 | 2013-01-03 04:16:18
```

I need to return the rows with

```
select XXX() is in between  sdate and edate
```

Where `XXX()` is `current utc time  + 4:30.000`.
In pseudo code:

```
select count(*)
where ((current utc time  + 4:30.000) >= sdate
    && (current utc time  + 4:30.000) <= edate)
```

For starters, how do I get the current utc time + 4:30.000 in Postgres?

Comment: what's wrong with `current_timestamp between sdate and edate`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , please recheck the question..

Comment: Your Postgres version?

Answer (score 3):

```
select *
from some_table 
where current_timestamp at time zone 'UTC' + interval '4:30' minute BETWEEN sdate and edate;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get current utc time + 4:30.000 in postgres like this

```
 now() at time zone 'UTC' + interval '4:30.000'
 -- or current_timestamp at time zone 'UTC' + interval '4:30.000'
```

And your query would be like

```
SELECT *
FROM aTable
WHERE now() at time zone 'UTC' + interval '4:30.000' >= sdate
AND now() at time zone 'UTC' + interval '4:30.000' <= edate
```

You can out an [SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/16e66/20)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the current Postgres version **9.2** you could use the new range type: [`tsrange` or **`tstzrange`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rangetypes.html):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
   tbl_id int PRIMARY KEY
  ,t_range tstzrange  -- why tstzrange? see below ..
);
```

Then you can simply:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE (now() + interval '00:04:30') <@ t_range
```

Or (see below):

```
...
WHERE (now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' + interval '00:04:30') <@ t_range
```

[**`<@`** .. "element is contained by" operator.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE)

To make this fast, add a GiST index:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_t_range_idx ON t_range USING gist (t_range);
```

Either way, you *need* to define whether upper and lower border are *included* or *excluded*.

[**->SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/5b6dd/1)

#### "current utc time + 4:30.000"

If you want what the literal value of UTC time right now, transfered and re-interpreted at your local time zone - being a different point in time than "now":

```
SELECT now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

If you actually want the "current time", vulgo "now", the time zone is irrelevant.
There is only ***one*** "now". Always and everywhere (with the possible exception of Hollywood movies. Time zones are just different ways of *representing* that value. The current UTC time is **the same** as the current eastern standard time or any other current local time. That's also how Postgres operates internally.

If you want "now", just take the local timestamp.

If you want to (or have to) operate with various time zones you should be using `timestamptz` instead of `timestamp` to begin with.

More on how Postgres handles time zones in this related answer:
[Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the correct time zone:

```
where current_timestamp at time zone 'AFT' BETWEEN sdate and edate;
```

`AFT` for Afghanistan and `IRDT` for Iran